# how do i track a .txt file using Git?

Tags: git, text-files

As I write in a .txt file, how do I keep track of the changes? This will be from the creation of the file until I'm finished with it. Does the file need to be in a certain place? Special commands required? I have never used open source management software before, so as much advice as you have to spare would be welcome.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: I suggest you might try http://git-scm.com/ or try searching SO  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to read the [**Git Book**](http://book.git-scm.com/) then.

You have to

1. Initialize your repository

   ```
   cd folder
   git init
   ```
2. Create and add files

   ```
   vim file.txt
   git add file.txt
   ```
3. Commit changes

   ```
   git commit -m"Added some more lines"
   ```
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 whenever you make changes to your file(s) and want to add them to your repository.

**But:** You really have to read a tutorial before and get familiar with the basic commands. You don't have to create a git repository at a certain place, any folder will do.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a repository and add the file to it.
[A simple command list can be found here.](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html)

All you'd do would be something like the following in an empty directory containing your text file only:

```
git init .
git add mytextfile.txt
```

Then, every time you'd like to commit/save current changes or the current version of the file, type:

```
git commit
```

or (to add a commit message that can be seen in the commit/version history later on)

```
git commit -m "Added chapter 5"
```

Comment: No, when you only type `git commit` then the default editor opens. If you don't add any text, then the commit is not created.